# Count number of comparisons for QuickSort

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I want to count the number of comparisons in quicksort. In order to do so, I introduced a counting variable c. Although I think the implementation is correct, the counter is significantly higher than with insertion sort, which should not be the case. Have I done something wrong?

Here is my code.

```
def quick_sort(a):                 
    c = 0
    c = quickSortImpl(a, 0, len(a)-1, c)
    return c


def quickSortImpl(a, l, r, c):
    if r > l:                                            
        k, c = partition(a, l, r, c)
        c = quickSortImpl(a, l, k-1, c)
        c = quickSortImpl(a, k+1, r, c)
    return c

def partition(a, l, r, c):
    pivot = a[r]    
    i  = l           
    j  = r - 1
    while True:
        c += 1
        while i < r and a[i] <= pivot:
            c += 1
            i += 1               
        c += 1
        while j > l and a[j] >= pivot:
            c += 1
            j -= 1              
        if i < j:                
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]  
        else:                    
            break                 
    a[r] = a[i]                                             
    a[i] = pivot                 
    return i, c
```

[Click here for comparison between Insertion Sort vs Quick Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7U50.png)

Comment: Could you give an example for what the code outputs for `c`  for a given array and what it actually should output for `c`?

Comment: for the array b = [3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 8] the count is 36. To be honest, I am not sure what the count should be. But it should be have like n*log(n), while n is the array length. When I plot it however, it behaves more like n^2 and is generally worse than insertion sort:

Comment: Try with a larger input and see if the issue persists. But also, try reasoning through it: how many comparisons do you expect for a given call to `partition`, depending on the inputs? Are you actually getting that many comparisons (check `c` before and after)?

Comment: I added a plot for the comparison between quick sort and insertion sort. What I would have expected is: I only make a comparison within the two inner while loops of partition. But I have to add 1 more count each in case the while loop condition is false.